Flutter UI Freezes Despite Using compute for Decryption Function
I'm facing an issue with a decryption function in my Flutter app. I've moved the decryption logic to a top-level function and used compute to offload the heavy computation to a separate isolate. Despite this, the UI still freezes while the decryption is in progress.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
// Top-level function for decryption logic
Future<String?> _aesCBCDecrypt(Map<String, String> params) async {....}

// Main function to be called
Future<String?> aesCBCDecrypt(
  String encryptedText,
  String encryptionSecretKey,
  String ivHex,
  String saltHex,
) async {
  return await compute(_aesCBCDecrypt, {
    'encryptedText': encryptedText,
    'encryptionSecretKey': encryptionSecretKey,
    'ivHex': ivHex,
    'saltHex': saltHex,
  });
}

class DecryptButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DecryptButtonState createState() => _DecryptButtonState();
}

class _DecryptButtonState extends State<DecryptButton> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  String? decryptedText1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = true;
              });

              // Define the required variables
              String text = 'abc123xyz';
             
              const ivHex = "ivKey"; 
              const saltKey = "saltKey"; 

              // Perform decryption
              final decryptedData = await aesCBCDecrypt(text, decryptSecret, ivHex, saltKey);

              print('Decrypted Data: $decryptedData');

              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
                decryptedText1 = decryptedData;
              });

              print('Decrypted Text: $decryptedText1');
            },
            child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : const Text('decrypt text'),
          ),
          if (decryptedText1 != null) Text(decryptedText1!),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Despite using compute to offload the decryption, the UI still freezes.
Is there something I'm missing? How can I ensure the UI remains responsive while performing the decryption?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Tried using compute to offload the task but still UI freezes.

You can try calling the compute callback without await just to see what happens. But based on the documentation, there's no benefit. The documentation states that "On web platforms this will run the callback on the current event loop," which is exactly what you want to avoid. As an alternative, you can execute this kind of operation on your backend

Thanks for the suggestion @JilmarXa but as per the requirements encryption and decryption both has to be done on client as well as on server.
